# Is chrome vulnerable to any zero day exploits right now?

Tags: chrome

i was using flvtbo youtube converter and i had to enable javascript.

i saw an ad come up from "multiadblock.com" which tried to lure me into downloading a chrome extension, but of course i didn't even proceed

after browsing through the google extension store i noticed that no such extension exists.

flvto even redirected me into their website. which did not even load(because i have javascript disabled :p)

However. i did have javascript enabled for flvto to pop the the malicious ad.

As to what the website actually contains . **Obviously the website is malicious**

Comment: `Is chrome vulnerable to any zero day exploits right now?`  There is no way to know, because by definition, a 'zero day' exploit is an exploit that is publicly known for zero days.

Comment: do you think that website could infect a payload onto the latest version of chrome as a guest user under the latest windows updates?

Comment: I haven't looked at the web site, and I'm not going to.  But, from what you are saying, it tries to lure you into downloading and installing an extension (which apparently is not approved by the Google store).  So, it's a social engineering attack, and the extension is the attack vector - it is not that the site is somehow exploiting a vulnerability in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Is chrome vulnerable to any zero day exploits right now?

If issue is known by public community such as stackexachange it may not be a zero day vulnerability any more. Because Chrome developers release patch update soon as possible.

There are two type of zero day vulnerabilities.

First one only one specific security specialist or Hackers knows about vulnerability still not aware by public community including product owner. Therefore patch is not released yet. (*Any vulnerability previously unknown until patch/solution released, it will be a zero day vulnerability* )

Second type of zero day vulnerability is product owner knows about that but not publicly announced and patched.

According to your question you are accessing some malicious web site and it is not related to vulnerability of Chrome at all. But particular extension developer may exploit on zero day vulnerability on chrome and it quiet possible situation. But it is need not to be a zero day vulnerability, extension may exploit on unpatched chrome application as well.

In some cases, It could be fully legitimate application which has no any harmful code inside and they will be able to collect data while you are browsing.

Therefore be alert on when you are online. Always check URLs before accessing and Use update Anti malware application which support for internet security and it will provide fundamental level security.